# Convert changed GregorianCalendar to Date

Tags: java, android, gregorian-calendar

I have the following code in a method:

```
final String WEEK_OF_YEAR    = "w";

GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
calendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, Integer.valueOf(get(WEEK_OF_YEAR)) + 1); 
//The get(WEEK_OF_YEAR) returns the actual week of the year

DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EE, dd.MM.yyyy");
return formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
```

so what I want is to get a `String` of the format `"EE, dd.MM.yyyy"` of the next week.
so it looks like that `calendar.getTime()` is returning the actual week...

Comment: It's really not clear what you mean. Why aren't you just adding a week instead, anyway? Or even add 7 days?

Comment: What does this method return, and what do you expect it to return?

Comment: this method returns a date of the next week in the format "EE, dd.MM.yyyy"

Comment: @JonSkeet how can I just add a week?

Comment: What is the point of calling `Integer.valueOf`?

Comment: @Simon I would try the `add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1)`

Comment: @Simon: What Peter said ;)

Comment: cause this method returns the week as a ```String```. like ```"32"```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the next week, use this code:

```
 GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
 calendar.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1);
```

Note that new Calender() returns the current week. I do not know GregorianCalendar(). You may have a try.